# How do speedrunners accurately measure their times?

Tags: speedrun

I was watching a few videos about NES Super Mario Bros speedrunning and I'm confused how they get such precise timings.  They clearly can't be personally hitting a button to stop or start a clock, because the timer tracks down to the millisecond.  But I also don't see how they can have software do it both because they're playing on a console and because of run validity concerns; additional software opens up the risk of cheating.  And they can't just be going over a recording and counting frames because many of these runs are done live on Twitch.

So how do they do it?  I'm interested in the topic in general, not just SMB.

Comment: audio/OCR/image recognition, memory hooking/reading or emulators; [LiveSplit](https://livesplit.org/) can integrate into almost everything on the PC it is running on.

Answer (score 1):

There's two parts needed to answer this question. Firstly, the commonly used timer program [LiveSplit](https://livesplit.org/) supports [automatic time splitting](https://github.com/LiveSplit/LiveSplit.AutoSplitters). It needs to be configured on a game-by-game basis via image/audio recognition or reading memory for PC games and emulated games. In the case of SMB1, [auto splitters are available](https://www.speedrun.com/smb1/resources/816lq).

Secondly, video game speedrun records are typically tracked by [speedrun.com](https://www.speedrun.com/). For a player to have their speedrun record recognized, they will need to submit their run for review. Moderators do not solely rely on a streamer's live timer. When moderators "[retime](https://www.speedrun.com/raotd/forums/gwxox)" a run after the fact, it's common that the actual time may differ  from what's shown on the timer. (See also [this SMB1 retiming tool](https://www.speedrun.com/smb1/resources/0ejex))

For reference, [Speedrun.com's Super Mario Bros 1 leaderboards](https://www.speedrun.com/smb1) have specific rules on how runs are timed. (Specific sections bolded for emphasis)

> #### Goal
>
> Beat the game as fast as possible by any means necessary.
>
> #### Timing
>
> Timing is done using the SDA standard:
>
> Start - The frame "400" appears in the top right corner after selecting 1 player.
>
> End - The frame all sprites are invisible after touching the axe in 8-4.
>
> #### Category Rules
>
> - Using save states to the title screen is prohibited. You must use the reset function on your emulator or console and the reset must be shown in the video.
> - **Only runs faster than 5:03 (5:08 for PAL) are represented with milliseconds on the leaderboard.** Please do not include milliseconds if your time is not below this threshold.
> - **It is recommended to hold onto full session, split files, input files, etc. in the event that a moderator requests additional evidence for verification.**
>
> Times below 4:57.000 are treated with additional scrutiny. The following is required for submissions below this threshold:
>
> - The run's full session must be included in the submission's description. Additional attempt sessions may be requested at the discretion of the moderation team.
> - For emulator submissions, the run must have an input display visible at all times. A hand-cam or input visualizer program is sufficient for emulators without a built-in input display.